# How to get user input from an instance of a class (object)

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx

I'm trying to implement a Linked list program using JavaFX. But I'm stuck.
I will show you my code's logic to get you in the picture.
this is the `Link` Class, which is only available inside it's package.

```
class Link
{
int ID;
Link next;
Link(int ID)
{
    this.ID=ID;
    next=null;
}
}
```

and then, the `LinkedList` Class, which the methods located there:

```
public class LinkedList extends Application
{
Link head,tail, searchKey;
@FXML
Button addToHead;
@FXML
Button addToTail;
@FXML
Button print;
void addToHead(){//My Code goes here...}
void addToTail(){//My Code goes here...}
```

and for handling events, I've created this method:

```
@FXML
public void handleAnyButtonClicked() {
final Button[] b = {new Button()};
b[0].setOnAction((event) -> {
b[0] = (Button) event.getSource();
final String bText = b[0].getText();
if(bText.equals("addToHead")){
addToTail(Link);// --> the problem is here
}
else if(bText.equals("addToTail")){
//   addToTail(Link);// --> the problem is here
}
else if(bText.equals("print")){
print();
}
});
```

But before the function being called, a new linkedlist object must be created.
How can I solve this problem. 
**Note:**
I want the outputs to be shown in the console, only the methods want them to be called using the buttons.

Comment: Move your GUI logic to a separate class and also move your `LinkedList` to a separate class. `LinkedList` should not extend `Application`, because it does not make any sense. `LinkedList` is not an `Application`. Your `Application` just uses the `LinkedList`. So you should create an instance of `LinkedList` as a member variable of your new `Application` class.

Comment: So, the problem is only there do you mean? Also Forgot to mention that if there's an object parameters how can I get its value from user input?